# Поиск пустой строки в MySQL

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Мужики, есть вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM `transformer` WHERE `tname`='T' AND `Apri`=''
```

и запись в базе, где:

`tname = "T"` и `"Apri" = 0`

И этот запрос возвращает `CNT = 1`

Т.е. эти запросы идентичны:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM `transformer` WHERE `tname`='T' AND `Apri`=''
```

и

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM `transformer` WHERE `tname`='T' AND `Apri`='0'
```

Как отличить ноль (тип поля `Apri - INT(11)`) от пустой строки? Потому что у меня может быть записан и ноль, и пустая строка, в ячейку.

Comment: если тип поля `Apri` - `INT(11)`, то почему речь о строках?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Выберет все строки в которых Apri == 0

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM transformer WHERE Apri=0
```

Выберет все строки, в которых Apri == NULL

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM transformer WHERE Apri is NULL
```

Comment: В БД может быть записан ноль, или пустая строка, или любое другое число. И мне надо различать что записано в ячейку, ноль или пустая строка. Запросы, которые я привел в вопросе возвращают единицу, хотя первый должен возвратить ноль, а второй единицу.

Comment: тип поля Apri INT(11), из этого следует что Ваше "пустая строка" эквивалентно моему NULL. Если нужно выбрать все элементы с пустой строкой, то пишит в запросе Apri is NULL, если все элементы со значением 0 - Apri=0 . А вот по поводу того, что должен sql, когда вы сравниваете строковую константу с полем int, это еще вопрос спорный...

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснение.

Answer (score 3):

поле типа INT, а сравнение идет с символьным полем... Тут действительно, надо думать о типах. В общем случае, так делать не следует.